# Are there any statistics available for users of this community by country?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Questions:

1. Are there any stats available for how many users are there by country?
2. When this site started or was proposed, were there people from only India or other countries as well? Though I am interested in knowing about the number of users from Nepal, or NRI, I am interested in knowing more about neo-Hindu adherents from West.

Apologies if those are off-topic or if those were asked earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Data Stack Exchange site, where we can create queries to get the data from any Stack Exchange site. Fortunately requested query is already present. And as per that query result, it seems there are **50 users from Nepal**. You can check the result set [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/53058/top-users-by-country?CountryName=Nepal).

But many users prefer not to disclose their place name, so they write something else. For example check this user: [TheLittleNaruto](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/647/thelittlenaruto?tab=profile), who lives in a country called "Leaf Village" which doesn't exist in reality.

So conclusion is, the resulted number may or may not be true considering above example.

Comment: Just to add, the correct data about the users could be retrieved from IP addresses from which those user accounts are being operated. But due to privacy concerns and policies, that data won't be available publicly. So, from SEDE, you'll always get a rough idea and the results may not be reliable.

Comment: Damn. I am not even in top 30 of my country

Comment: @Carmensandiego In that case! I am very lucky! I do not even have competition. ;-)